# I'd like to use jQuery to copy the file path in one input field and show it in a second field

Tags: jquery

I'm using something like this but its not working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var content = $("#file_field").val();
    $("input.browser_hidden").val( content );
});
```

Any suggestions? Even hard coding a value in the the second field isn't showing up.

Here is the html I'm using:

```
    <div class="file_wrapper"> 
       <input type="file" name="file_field" id="file_field">
       <div class="file_wrapper_inner"> 
          <input class="browser_hidden" value="something in here" type="text" />
          <a class="button_browse" href="#">Browse</a>
       </div> 
    </div>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is make the file input hidden (100% transparent) and when the input is clicked the file path is mirrored in the .browser_hidden input field.

Comment: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, please. Without something more than this, this question is impossible to answer. And showing 'something like' what you're working with? It'd be better to see *what* you're working with. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), though.

Comment: At the moment this code runs, I don't think `#file_field` has a value yet. That does not explain though why `$("input.browser_hidden").val( 'some content' )` would not work (if that is what you meant by hard coding). Are the selectors correct? What is the type of `input.browser_hidden`?

Comment: Should work. If it doesn't then the jQuery selectors don't match the HTML.

Comment: Here is the html I'm using: <div class="file_wrapper">
<input type="file" name="file_field" id="file_field">
<div class="file_wrapper_inner">
<input class="browser_hidden" value="something in here" type="text" /><a class="button_browse" href="#">Browse</a></div>
</div>

Comment: @dbizzell: Edit your question to add the HTML. Code is not readable in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set a value in an `<input type="file" />` with javascript. For security reasons.

In case your 2nd field is not a file input, the code above still doesn't work for one reason - you are executing it only once, when the document is loaded. And at that moment the file input does not have a value. You should attach an `onchange` listener to the file input and then transfer the value.

But I'm not sure if it is a good idea to do that. The value of the file input might not be consistent across browsers. For example in Firefox it contains the full path, while in Chrome it appears to contain only the filename (haven't checked if it is the case with js access). But anyway, the filename is available to the server side when submitting the form.

Comment: What if `input.browser_hidden` is not a file input?

Comment: added a whole new paragraph for that case :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, using change on the input file do the trick (instead of calling just once when the document is ready).

```
$(function(){
    $('#file_field').change(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        $('.browser_hidden').val('Selected: ' + elem.val() );
    }); 
});​
```

[Here's a working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8uKvk/3/).